# Running php script from shell does not echo anything

Tags: php, shell

I have a very simple test.php file:

```
<?php

echo 'Hello World';
```

Then I run it from Mac Shell: `php test.php`
But it does not echo anything. Looks like it's blocked for some reason, like this:

[image: Running php script from shell shows nothing]

If I use invalid syntax in the file, for example:

```
<?php

invalid syntax
```

Then I can see the error output:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'syntax' (T_STRING) in .../test.php on line 3

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'syntax' (T_STRING) in .../test.php on line 3
```

What's wrong with it?

**FYI:**

- Running `php -i` can print php.ini info
- Running `echo 'test'` can print 'test'

Comment: what do you see if you run $ echo 'test'

Comment: Which command you have tried actually. I mean what you meant by Samples

Comment: @SanjayKumarNS Samples is just the containing folder name. I run the command in that folder.

Comment: @PradeepSanjaya `$ echo 'test'` will print 'test'

Comment: Maybe **php** is aliased (try `which php` or run `\php test.php`).

Comment: @fardjad Thanks! It works if I use `/usr/local/.../php test.php`. I think you're right, cos I installed both php 5.4 and php 5.6 (via homebrew). But I get nothing when I run `alias | grep php`, do you know why? Btw, please add your answer :)

Comment: @fardjad I have a "php" folder in my "Samples" folder, if I remove this "php" folder, it works in all case now! Please add your answer, I'll upvote it. Without your comment, I won't be able to figure out the real cause. Thanks!

Comment: @fardjad But it's funny that if I remove my custom php folder and then re-create it, and add a few php files in the folder. It still works!

Comment: @MouhongLin Glad I could be of help. Well, apparently **php** was not aliased but what happened might be related to a **zsh** feature called **AUTO_CD**. Basically it lets you switch directories without typing **cd**. **AUTO_CD** can be disabled by adding **unsetopt auto_cd** to your **.zshrc** file. In regards to your last comment, I have no idea why it behaves this way but you might be able to reproduce the problem after restarting your terminal session or executing **rehash** on **samples** directory.

Comment: @fardjad Thanks. I get enough information now. Could you add your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turning my comments into an answer [as](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34782061/running-php-script-from-shell-does-not-echo-anything?noredirect=1#comment57311447_34782061) [requested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34782061/running-php-script-from-shell-does-not-echo-anything?noredirect=1#comment57436373_34782061):

Here are two possible reasons why php command doesn't work as expected:

1. Maybe it is aliased (try `which php` or prepend a **backslash (\)** to the command)
2. You mentioned that you had a directory named **php** on your working directory. Well, **zsh** has a feature called [**AUTO_CD**](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Intro/intro_16.html#IDX205) that may have interfered in this case. Basically **AUTO_CD** allows you to switch directories without typing **cd** and can be disabled by adding `unsetopt autocd` to [zshrc](/questions/tagged/zshrc) file.

Comment: I think i got the cause. When I'm seeing the issue, I'm letting my PHPStorm to listen to xdebug connections (doesn't hit any break point). If I stop PHPStorm, it works again.